# How to generate empty migration in EF Core code-first while ignoring pending changes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am aware that the `add-migration` command will generate a new migration file with empty `Up()` and `Down()` methods.

However, I have an error when building which means the migration doesn't get created.

How do I just create a legitimate migration file in spite of the build error?

I want to ignore the error and just create an empty migration file because I need to rename a table and column 'manually' (neither of which have corresponding Models in the code).

I want to do this using migrations to ensure all other team members apply the same changes automatically.

So I can't create a blank migration because of the error and I can't fix the error (using SQL in a migration) because I can't create a migration file.

Comment: You can't and I think you shouldn't. First solve your errors and than add the migration.

Comment: What kind of error are you facing? Can tell me that?

Comment: The error refers to `The skip navigation 'MyModel.CollectionProperty' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it.`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a migration without building is dangerous. The tools need to know the current state of the model. If a stale, interim model is used, the next migration will probably be wrong and getting everything back in sync won't be easy.

Fix the error before generating a migration--especially if it's an error with your EF Core mode.